# How to open a drive dialog in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I want to be able to allow users to share their google drive documents in my php app engine app. I know there  is the javascript library to create dialogs but I'm unsure about how this works with app engine. Does anyone know the best way to open a share dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thi is completely javascript library, it will work on app engine just like anywhere else.

Just read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) or for example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054).